# Do a task regardless of upstream task status

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow

I have a relatively simple DAG defined as follows:

```
set_variables >> create_conf_file >> check_running_job >> transform_data >> update_variables
create_conf_file >> remove_conf_file
check_running_stat_job >> remove_conf_file
transform_openidm_data >> remove_conf_file
update_orc_file_variable >> remove_conf_file
```

My goal here is to ensure that `remove_conf_file` is always executed regardless of the status of all previous tasks.

I've tried to use `trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE` in my `PythonOperator` call, but `remove_conf_file` is only executed if all previous tasks are done.
If task `check_running_stat_job` fails, the `remove_conf_file` task won't be executed.

I want the file to be removed whatever the status of upstream tasks is, DONE, FAILED, NOT DONE.

I've tried several DAG configurations but none seems to work.

**[EDIT]**
Here's the DAG tree view and DAG view in Airflow:

[image: DAG standard view]

[image: DAG tree view]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the DAG ? It seems there are two disconnected components in your DAG. Is that true ? Also, do you want to run `remove_conf_file` as soon any one of the upstream tasks in completed/failed/skipped ?

Comment: @MohammedKashif I've added pictures. I want that `remove_file` when everything as worked or anything failed between `create_conf_file` and `update_variable`. or anyother thing, if a task do not fails or changes or anything whatever happen file need to be removed in the end.

Comment: The ALL_DONE trigger looks properly configured. Can you check that the upstream tasks have reached any of SUCCESS, SKIPPED, UPSTREAM_FAILED or FAILED state?

Comment: My point is if any of my task fails for a reason try to do something at last, but if check_running_config_stat_job fails it won't trigger start_etl and won't trigger either remove_conf_file

Answer (score 0):

I've replicated the task structure displayed in your image and successfully ran the task `remove_conf_file` after task `spark_etl` failed:

[image]

The key was adding `trigger_rule='all_done'` to the `remove_conf_file` task. This doesn't mean that all upstream tasks need to be executed successfully, just that they need to be finished (irrespective of success or failure). I've used BashOperator instead of PythonOperator you mention in your question.

This [git repository](https://github.com/colourCoder17/Airflow) contains corresponding dockerfile with DAG.

**EDIT:**

For the reference, here is what the successful code looks like if we want to test failing of `spark_etl` task and subsequent successful execution of `remove_conf_file` task:

```
t4 = BashOperator(
    task_id='spark_etl',
    bash_command='exit 123"',          # simulation of task failure
    dag=dag)
    
t6 = BashOperator(
    task_id='remove_conf_file',
    bash_command='echo "Task 6"',
    dag=dag,
    trigger_rule='all_done')
```

*(Full code can be found in my git repository mentioned above.)*

Comment: I'll try it, but as you said it needs to be executed, if a task fails, downstream task are not executed. But I'll try it, I'm curious.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I actually meant that with the `trigger_rule='all_done'`, the `remove_conf_file` can be successfully executed even after `spark_etl` task fails. The keyword 'all done' is confusing because it sounds like failed or skipped doesn't count as 'done'. In this case though, 'done' means something like 'done with running (or attempting to run) the task' (whatever the task status is).

Comment: I know now when it's not working, as soon as a task fails DAG is marked for retry, and only the final retry goes to the end. I'm pretty sure that's waht causing my issue. I'll try it and confirm it, if it is the case I'll open an issue on Airflow github as I think it's important